# Winform Custom Control: Why Setter not called when used from Constructor?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an initial value property like this:

```
    [Category("Main")]
    [Description("Intial Value")]
    [DefaultValue(10)]
    public int InitialValue
    {
        get { return m_initialValue; }
        set { 
            m_initialValue = value;
            this.TrackBar.Value = this.m_initialValue;
        }
    }
```

So in my constructor I do this for example:

```
        this.InitialValue = 10;
```

To my surprise when dragging the custom control on a form the setter is not called so that my trackbar value is not synchronized.

Why ?

Only when I change the property in dialog box the setter is called.

Comment: May be some exception occurred before reaching the code `this.InitialValue = 10;`

Comment: I can't see how, it's just a basic tutorial sample I made for myself nothing complex :)

Comment: You can try by yourself will take 2 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to take your advice as suggested in one of the comments:

> You can try by yourself will take 2 minutes.

So I did (it took about 3 minutes), and **I was unable to reproduce the behavior that you described.**

Here are the exact steps that I followed:

1. Created a new Windows Forms Application.
2. Added a new User Control to my project.
3. Opened the new User Control in design view and added a `TrackBar` control (leaving the `TrackBar` control's properties all set to their defaults).
4. Added the following code to the User Control class (exactly the same as you posted above, with the addition of a private field `m_initialValue` that you omitted from the original example):

   ```
   public class UserControl1 : UserControl
   {
      public UserControl1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          this.InitialValue = 10;
      }


      [Category("Main")]
      [Description("Intial Value")]
      [DefaultValue(10)]
      public int InitialValue
      {
          get { return m_initialValue; }
          set
          {
              m_initialValue = value;
              this.trackBar1.Value = this.m_initialValue;
          }
      }


      int m_initialValue;
   }
   ```
5. Built the project.
6. Opened the default Form (`Form1`) that was created with the new project in design view.
7. Dragged the User Control that I had just created (`UserControl1`) out of the toolbox where it was automatically placed and onto the surface of the form.

The indicator on the slider bar appeared all the way to the *right* side (the correct and expected position given the default `Maximum` value of 10). Now, you tell me: **What are we doing differently?**

Comment: Well I have restarted again, I cannot reproduce the behavior I have still the file which bugs but can't see real difference.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `[Browsable(true)]` .

Comment: Why would this make a difference? Whether or not the property is displayed in the Properties window at design time shouldn't affect if its setter gets called, and the default value for the `BrowsableAttribute` is true anyway. The question says that he can change the property at design time (or at least I'm pretty sure that's the "dialog box" he refers to).

Answer (score 0):

The key portion of your question is here:

> when dragging the custom control on a form

You're still in the designer, and the designer cheats a bit to render things.  Does this still happen when you actually run the application?